# Trying to implement the interface Comparable

Tags: java, comparable

just wondering what this error means and how I should fix this.

Error: The type Student must implement the inherited abstract method java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(java.lang.Object)

I am trying to implement this so I can use the class's compareTo Method.

Thanks so much for your help!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Comparable
{
 private String name;
 private double gpa;
 public Student()
{
  name = "";
  gpa = 0.0;
}//end default constructor

 public Student(String n, double g)
 {
   name = n;
   gpa = g;
 }//end two arg constructor

public double getGPA()
{
  return gpa;
}

 public String getName()
 {
   return name;
 }

 public void setGPA(double g)
 {
   this.gpa = g;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
  this.name = n;
}

public String toString()
{
  return " Name: " + name + " GPA: " + gpa;
}

public static void compareTo()
{


}
}//end class
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is implement the comparable interface and override the compareTo() method in the class you wanted to be sorted. Inside the compareTo method you must mention on which basis your object should be sorted. The below code will be helpful in this:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
 private String name;
 private double gpa;
 public Student()
{
  name = "";
  gpa = 0.0;
}//end default constructor

 public Student(String n, double g)
 {
   name = n;
   gpa = g;
 }//end two arg constructor

public double getGPA()
{
  return gpa;
}

 public String getName()
 {
   return name;
 }

 public void setGPA(double g)
 {
   this.gpa = g;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
  this.name = n;
}

public String toString()
{
  return " Name: " + name + " GPA: " + gpa;
}

public Integer compareTo(Student student)
{
 // if object is getting sorted on the basis of Name
   return this.getName().compareTo(student.getName())
// if object is getting sorted on the basis of gpa
   return Double.valueOf(this.gpa).compareTo(Double.valueOf(student.getGPA()));
}
}//end class
```

Since you are using primitive data type double instead of Object Double so we need to get the object using Double.valueOf(this.gpa)
You should use only one return statement as per your requirement.

Comment: Your code will not compile, `compareTo` should not be a `static` method and you cannot reference `this` in a `static` method

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the following changes to your code in order to implement the `Comparable` interface correctly.

(1) Specify the type of object your class is comparable with:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>
```

(2) And the corresponding signature of the `compareTo` method is as follow:

```
public int compareTo(Student other)
```

And of course you have to implement the body of the `compareTo` method too.

- If the `this` instance is "smaller" than the argument `other` then `compareTo` should return a *negative* number.
- If the `this` instance is "larger" than the argument `other` then `compareTo` should return a *positive* number.
- If the `this` instance is considered to be "of the same value" as the argument `other` then `compareTo` should return `0`.

You may refer to the [official java document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for more information about the implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Note that  `Interface Comparable<T>` is a generic interface. Here `T` is type (Class, Interface mostly). You want to compare `Student` with another type (`Student`).

So you have to pass type(`T`) `Student` to   `Comparable<T>`.

Hence you change it to

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>
```

Another point you **have to** implement the `Comparable<T>` interface as **same method signature and return type** to `Student` class.

```
public int compareTo(Student anotherStudent)
```

You have written

```
public static void compareTo()
```

which not follow the interface `Comparable<T>` **method signature and return type** in `Student` class.

Here you should implement your domain specific logic. I don't know how you want to implement it ? You can compare the name alphabetically or base on their CGPA.

Comment: Your code will not compile, `compareTo` should have `public` accessibility, you cannot assign weaker access privileges when overriding a method